# Velocity and acceleration of composition of curves in SE(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, classical-mechanics

Let $\xi_0(t), \xi_1(t) \in \mathbb R^6$ with $\xi_i = [\xi_{i0}, ..., \xi_{i5}]^T$.

Let

$$\exp(\xi_i) = \exp\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\xi_{i2} & \xi_{i1} & \xi_{i3}\\
\xi_{i2} & 0 & -\xi_{i0} & \xi_{i4}\\
-\xi_{i1} & \xi_{i0} & 0 & \xi_{i5}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \in SE(3)$$

where $SE(3)$ is the Special Euclidean Group of dimension 3.

Given:

$$\xi_0(t),~~~~ \frac{d}{dt} \xi_0(t),~~~~ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \xi_0(t)$$

and

$$\xi_1(t),~~~~ \frac{d}{dt} \xi_1(t),~~~~ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \xi_1(t)$$

Let $T(t) := \exp(\xi_0(t)) \exp(\xi_1(t))$

Let a rigid object be travelling along the trajectory $T(t)$.

What is the object's body-frame acceleration $a$ and angular velocity $\omega$?